# How to manipulate a .xlsx data with using nested for loops in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, xlsx, data-manipulation

This is what the sample looks like:

```
Year Categories January   February March April      May      June      July    August September   October   November     December

1990          A  4564.0   465465.0    12   468   4884.0  12788.00   4218.00 -58445.86 -90643.00 -122840.1 -155037.29 -187234.4286

1990          B  6487.0   421214.0   878  2112 421283.0  56456.00  54654.00    515.00    212.00     515.0     212.00     515.0000

1990          C 42862.0      512.0   484    48    515.0    212.00    515.00 137858.33     48.00  137858.3      48.00     465.0000

1990          D    15.0  -169222.7    90   456 137858.3     48.00    465.00 135673.83    778.00  135673.8     778.00      12.0000

1990          E 19164.0  -401699.2  -304   246 135673.8    778.00     12.00 133489.33     57.00  133489.3      57.00     478.0000

1991          A 21436.8  -634175.7  -698    36 133489.3     57.00    478.00 131304.83      3.00  131304.8       3.00     331.3333

1991          B 23709.6  -866652.2 -1092  -174 131304.8      3.00  -8210.60 129120.33  30425.33  129120.3  -11463.57     337.8333

1992          A 32800.8 -1796558.2 -2668 -1014 122566.8 -27597.89 -29087.86 292051.00  82253.33  331147.5  -12728.17     363.8333

1992          B 35073.6 -2029034.7 -3062 -1224 120382.3 -32976.00 -34307.17 321333.47  95210.33  367329.4  -14420.56     370.3333

1992          C 37346.4 -2261511.2 -3456 -1434 118197.8 -38354.11 -39526.49 350615.94 108167.33  403511.2  -16112.96     376.8333
```

Hey guys, first of all sorry for the format of the sample data. I am newb in stackoverflow and R. I have a problem about manipulation of a data in R. I want to use nested for-loops to manipulate this data.

What I want is exactly this:

I want to keep the A, B, C, D, E categories fixed on a "Category" column and put the data of the months that are next to them. Like January 1990, February 1990, ...., December 1990, January 1991, February 1991, ..., December 1991. These months will be side by side and will be in column form. Since there is no data for certain categories in some years, it should give a value of "0" in the months corresponding to those categories. How should I write a nested for loop for this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Actually I tried to write a loop like this but I can't write if-else statement in that loops. This code was for my actual big data but I created a sample data to upload there.

```
require(xlsx)
data = read.xlsx("sample-data.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")

library("tidyverse")
cat_data <- as.data.frame(data$Category)
unique_cat <- as.data.frame(unique(cat_data))

names(unique_cat)[names(unique_cat) == "data$Category"] <- "Category"
month_data <- subset(data, select = -c(1:4))
year_data <- subset(data, select = -c(2:16))


data %>% 
      for (i in 1:length(data)){
        for (j in 1:length(cat_data)){
          for (k in 1:length(month_data)){
              print(c(data)[i,j,k])
    }
  }
}
```

This is the expected output (Since it i:

```
Categories Jan.90    Feb.90 Mar.90 Apr.90   May.90 June.90 July.90
1          A   4564  465465.0     12    468   4884.0   12788    4218
2          B   6487  421214.0    878   2112 421283.0   56456   54654
3          C  42862     512.0    484     48    515.0     212     515
4          D     15 -169222.7     90    456 137858.3      48     465
5          E  19164 -401699.2   -304    246 135673.8     778      12
     Aug.90 Sep.90    Oct.90    Nov.90    Dec.90  Jan.91    Feb.91
1 -58445.86 -90643 -122840.1 -155037.3 -187234.4 21436.8 -634175.7
2    515.00    212     515.0     212.0     515.0 23709.6 -866652.2
3 137858.33     48  137858.3      48.0     465.0     0.0       0.0
4 135673.83    778  135673.8     778.0      12.0     0.0       0.0
5 133489.33     57  133489.3      57.0     478.0     0.0       0.0
  Mar.91 Apr.91   May.91 June.91 July.91   Aug.91   Sep.91   Oct.91
1   -698     36 133489.3      57   478.0 131304.8     3.00 131304.8
2  -1092   -174 131304.8       3 -8210.6 129120.3 30425.33 129120.3
3      0      0      0.0       0     0.0      0.0     0.00      0.0
4      0      0      0.0       0     0.0      0.0     0.00      0.0
5      0      0      0.0       0     0.0      0.0     0.00      0.0
     Nov.91   Dec.91  Jan.92   Feb.92 Mar.92 Apr.92   May.92
1      3.00 331.3333 32800.8 -1796558  -2668  -1014 122566.8
2 -11463.57 337.8333 35073.6 -2029035  -3062  -1224 120382.3
3      0.00   0.0000 37346.4 -2261511  -3456  -1434 118197.8
4      0.00   0.0000     0.0        0      0      0      0.0
5      0.00   0.0000     0.0        0      0      0      0.0
    June.92   July.92   Aug.92    Sep.92   Oct.92    Nov.92   Dec.92
1 -27597.89 -29087.86 292051.0  82253.33 331147.5 -12728.17 363.8333
2 -32976.00 -34307.17 321333.5  95210.33 367329.4 -14420.56 370.3333
3 -38354.11 -39526.49 350615.9 108167.33 403511.2 -16112.96 376.8333
4      0.00      0.00      0.0      0.00      0.0      0.00   0.0000
5      0.00      0.00      0.0      0.00      0.0      0.00   0.0000
```

Comment: Sounds like `tidyr::gather` is what you want

Comment: Actually I should not use 'tidyr' for this project so that I'm trying to use nested for loops to manipulate. @RichardTelford

Comment: It's kind of ironic that you use the `tidyverse` while also stating you don't want to use `tidyr`. Why use loops? Your last steps are also somewhat contradictory with `tidyverse` practice. There is no need to recall `data`, simply use `.` but again, why loops?

Comment: I used the ' tidyverse ' to get the unique categories because the categories change depend on years. I wrote a description for this. Let's say without tidyverse how can i manipulate the data with the nested for loops, I know if I use for loops the latency will be increase but that's the issue that using for loops for the manipulation @NelsonGon

Comment: I find it easier to understand looking at sample output, could you add a sample of the expected output?

Comment: I upload the expected output the months should be place side by side @NelsonGon